# AWS::Serverless::Function SES send mail policy in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ses, sam

I currently have the following definition for a `AWS::Serverless::Function` in my AWS SAM template:

```
PostSignUpConfirmationFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./dist/
      Handler: cognitoTriggers.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref Table
```

How can I also add the permission to use SES to send an email?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using [AWS SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/), you can simply utilize its [policy templates](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/policy_templates.rst) for granting access to send e-mails using SES. There is a policy template called `SESCrudPolicy` you can use. All you have to do is to provide the identity you want to grant access to. That'd look like:

```
PostSignUpConfirmationFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./dist/
      Handler: cognitoTriggers.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref Table
        - SESCrudPolicy:
            IdentityName: identity_you_want_to_use
```

Comment: Great thanks! And is that identity the email address in the `from` field?

Comment: Yes, according to AWS it's "an email address or domain that Amazon SES users use to send email" (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-authorization-overview.html).